# Can I intercept my iPhone's HTTP requests with my Mac?

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, ios

I'd like to be a man-in-the-middle between my iPhone and the internet for debugging purposes.  In particular, I'd like to convince my iPhone that a particular host on the internet is my local development machine, and that it should not actually connect out to the net (so the app believes it's contacting a production server when in fact it's hitting a local box).

I can disable 3G and use my Mac's ad-hoc WiFi, but adding `/etc/hosts` entries of course won't route requests to the local machine, since it's just doing NAT, not handling DNS or other protocols on behalf of the phone.

The only thing I can think of is to jailbreak it and mess with the hosts file on the device, but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it.  Can anyone think of another way of going about this?

Comment: Future readers: Set a HTTP proxy in your iPhone's network settings, using your Mac's IP. And on your Mac, install and run [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org). There's a good guide here: http://www.shubhro.com/2014/12/18/reverse-engineering-kayak-mitmproxy/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setup a DNS server on your mac, configure your router to use your mac as it's DNS server and create DNS entries that point to where you want them.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe it didn't think of that :). I might go a little bit simpler and just configure the device directly to use a DNS server on my Mac instead if getting the router involved, but the idea will work nonetheless.  Thanks!